# Install obfsproxy on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management

Is there any way to install obfsproxy on Ubuntu 20.04 ?

**Command** `sudo apt-get install -y obfsproxy`
returns
`E: Unable to locate package obfsproxy`

I've made a research and found that this package available only for ubuntu 16 and 18.
How could i install it on ubuntu  20 ?

UPD

Install python python-dev pip packages and run

pip install obfsproxy

After install it, run with

*/home/user/.local/bin/obfsproxy obfs3 socks ip:port*

Answer (score 2):

The name of the package is not `obfsproxy`, it's `obfs4proxy`:

```
obfs4proxy/focal 0.0.8-1 amd64
  pluggable transport proxy for Tor, implementing obfs4

simple-obfs/focal 0.0.5-6 amd64
  simple obfusacting plugin for shadowsocks-libev
```

To install it, you should run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install obfs4proxy
```

Comment: The first half of my answer is to show the user that what he is trying to install has a different name.

Answer (score 1):

For sake of other people who want to install obfsproxy on Ubuntu 20.04: you have to use python2.7 and pip.

You can install it with these four steps:

1. install python2.7

```bash
sudo apt install python2.7
sudo apt install python2
```

2. install python crypto

```bash
sudo apt install python2.7-crypto
```

3. install pip

```bash
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
sudo python2.7 get-pip.py
rm get-pip.py
```

4. install obfsproxy

```bash
pip install obfsproxy
sudo pip install obfsproxy
```

Comment: Being unfamiliar with obfsproxy, I need to ask: why, in step #4, do you install it twice (both with and without `sudo`?

Comment: i just wrote what i did to install it. i first ran it without sudo but it didn't install globally and the obfsproxy command didn't work. then i ran it with sudo and the obfsproxy command worked. probably just run it with sudo is enough but i didn't test it so i wrote both. and by the way, thanks for the edit. @MDeBusk

Comment: no need to run `sudo pip install obfsproxy`. the non-sudo version installs the package in a place like `/home/usrname/.local/bin/` which is not normally on your $PATH. Pip normally warns if it installs a package in a directory which is not in the path. Just add the directory to your $PATH to be able to execute the `obfsproxy` normally.

Comment: I am having issues in running this: sudo apt install python2.7-crypto
Is it instead something like: pip install cryptography" 
First won't install but with second installed too there are errors when I run pip installobfxproxy.

Answer (score 0):

To use obfsproxy you will need Python (>= 2.7) and pip. If you use Debian testing (or unstable) or a version of Ubuntu newer than Oneiric, this is easy:

```bash
apt-get install python2.7 python-pip python-dev build-essential libgmp-dev
```

**Step 1: Install Tor**

You will also need a development version of Tor. To do this, you
should use the [guide to install tor and deb.torproject.org-keyring](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#development).

You need Tor 0.2.4.x because it knows how to automatically report your obfsproxy address to BridgeDB.

**Step 2: Install obfsproxy**

If you have pip, installing obfsproxy and its dependencies should be a matter of a single command:

```bash
pip install obfsproxy
```

**Step 3: Set up Tor**

Now set up Tor. Edit your `/etc/tor/torrc` to add:

```
SocksPort 0
ORPort 443 # or some other port if you already run a webserver/skype
BridgeRelay 1
Exitpolicy reject *:*

## CHANGEME_1 -> provide a nickname for your bridge, can be anything you like
#Nickname CHANGEME_1
## CHANGEME_2 -> provide some email address so we can contact you if there's a problem
#ContactInfo CHANGEME_2

ServerTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3 exec /usr/local/bin/obfsproxy managed
```

Don't forget to uncomment and edit the CHANGEME fields.

**Step 4: Launch Tor and verify that it bootstraps**

Comment: remove asteriks in the pip install command, it got there accidentally ! :)

Comment: I don't need tor, i need only obfsproxy, and finaly i've installed it via pip. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know, it helped !